# Mudança de link com JavaScript ou PHP

Tags: php, javascript, link

Estou com um problema com um botão onde eu preciso mudar o link dele com javascript ou php.

Vamos lá!

Minha plataforma gera um formulário automático, porem eu não tenho acesso ao código fonte. O form coleta nome e e-mail e manda para a plataforma, por esse motivo que o formulário já é pronto. Porem ao coletar os dados, continua na mesma pagina, eu preciso redirecionar para outra pagina ao usuário clicar no botão e que o botão também continue com a funcionalidade dele de cadastrar os dados na plataforma, porem não tenho o código fonte como dito acima.

Eu consigo ver os id's, class, name e tudo mais pelo "inspecionar" do browser, gostaria de saber se tem algum jeito de redirecionar a pagina com js ou php sabendo que sei os atributos acima.

```
<div class="pages">
   <cxc.newsletter/>
</div>
```

Essa div é para chamar o formulário da plataforma já pronto.
Quando é exibido no navegador, mostra o formulário com os campos para preencher, e esses campos tem seus id, name, class que eu uso também para estilizar os inputs e button.

Comment: Por favor, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/246659/edit) sua pergunta e forneça [um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Como pretende fazer isso sem acesso ao código-fonte?

Comment: Eu possuo acesso ao html todo, de menos o que a plataforma gera, que é o que esta dentro da div que está no pergunta.

Comment: Esse <cxc.newsletter> chama na plataforma os inputs e o button, já com a classe definida, id, e name padrão... não tem como alterar, quero saber se com essas informações que tenho se eu consigo mudar o link do botão.

Comment: Já tentou utilizar o `addEventListener` do JavaScript?

Comment: Quando envia os dados para cadastro, a página recarrega ou é um Ajax?

Comment: O que vc não pode alterar é o destino do formulário, senão não irá cadastrar os dados enviados. Porém, há uma forma de redirecionar após o envio do formulário. É preciso saber o que altera na página após esse envio e sabendo disso, com JavaScript forçar um redirecionamento.

Comment: Não conheço o addEventListener  não Anderson :/

Comment: Na verdade não é um form, fui tentar fazer outro método e percebi agora! São só dois inputs de texto e um button apenas dentro daquela div.

Comment: Não importa se é um form. Tem que saber como funciona isso, como os dados são enviados, se a página recarrega etc. Essas informações são cruciais para uma solução.

Comment: A pagina não recarrega. E os dados são enviados por um código js via POST.

Comment: Entendi. Mas em seguida aparece uma mensagem de confirmação?

Comment: Sim, e caso não tenha sido preenchido um dos campos dai mostra a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Tudo bem. O que precisamos é saber quando o POST terminou. Com o "inspecionar elemento" do navegador, veja se a mensagem de confirmação possui um ID.

Comment: Tem sim, id, class tbm

Comment: Troque as ids da resposta pelas ids correspondentes e veja se funciona.

Comment: Ainda não entendi como você vai usar os dados se não tem acesso, você tem o html mas não tem o form de login?

Comment: Não é um login @WMomesso, são dois campos para "captar" dados e o botão para enviar. Eu possuo o código html,  porem não tenho o codigo que é gerado pela plataforma, que é a div que demonstrei na pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie um `addEventListener` para o botão, e quando ele for clicado, dará início a um `setInterval` que ficará checando se o `id` da `div` de confirmação existe na página. Quando ela existir, irá redirecionar para a página em `location.href`:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("dados")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
        temporizador = setInterval(function(){
            if(document.getElementById("id_da_div_de_confirmação")){
                clearInterval(temporizador);
                location.href = "página_para_aonde_quer_ir.html";
            }
        }, 10);
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Cara entendi o que você quis fazer, pensei que ia dar certo mas notei que o id da class muda conforme a pagina é atualizada.

`<div class="dados" id="NewsLetter_24c11322_25e5_49e7_8c80_3803db2a968c">` 

Será que no lugar do getElementById eu nao posso utilizar o `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: @GuilhermeLuis Pode sim, mas tem que ver se não existe outros elementos com a mesma class

Comment: @GuilhermeLuis Abre o console e bota `document.getElementsByClassName("dados").length`... se o resultado for 1, aí pode trocar

Comment: @GuilhermeLuis Vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: Cara pegou, porem ele esta redirecionando quando os campos não são preenchidos, o que posso fazer para arrumar isso ?

Comment: @GuilhermeLuis Isso não deveria acontecer. Só deveria redirecionar quando aparecesse a confirmação do envio dos dados.

Comment: @GuilhermeLuis Então a div de confirmação já existe antes de enviar os dados, e deve estar oculta. Vc teria que achar ela no código-fonte e ver como ela está, se está display: none ou alguma coisa assim.

Comment: Cara, meu código está assim: 

`<script>
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("newsletterButtonOK").addEventListener("click", function(){
        temporizador = setInterval(function(){
            if(document.getElementsByClassName("success")){            
                    clearInterval(temporizador);
                    location.href = "http://www.site.com.br/pagina";
                }            
        }, 10);
    });
}
</script>`

Comment: @GuilhermeLuis Troque o `if(document.getElementsByClassName("success"))` por `if(document.getElementsByClassName("success").length > 0)`

Comment: Troquei e continua redirecionando sem preencher, o que acho estranho é que com o `document.getElementsByClassName("succes").length` ou error. Ele está me retornando 1 se eu tiver na success ou se eu tiver na error e tentar `document.getElementsByClassName("error").length` ele me retorna 1, de resto me retorna 0.

Comment: Quando faço `if(document.getElementsByClassName("success").length > 0)` no console, me retorna true porem quando fui ver o código fonte, o sinal de maior não aparece, fui substituído por caracteres diferentes, sabe o que possa ser ? Está assim no codigo fonte `if(document.getElementsByClassName("success").length&gt;0)`

Comment: @GuilhermeLuis Faz o seguinte: antes de enviar o formulário, abre o console (F12) e coloca isso: `document.getElementsByClassName("success").length` e anota o valor que retorna... faça o mesmo depois do envio do formulário e anota o que retorna, e depois me diz os valores.

Comment: Antes de enviar = 0, depois de enviar = 1

Comment: @GuilhermeLuis Então está certo. O problema deve ser isso que vc falou, de substituir > por &gt;

Comment: Sim, também acho que deva ser isso. Sabe como posso arrumar ?

Comment: @GuilhermeLuis Altera para: `if(document.getElementsByClassName("success")[0])`

Comment: Cara, fiz com `  if(document.getElementsByClassName("success").length == 1)` e deu certo. Muito obrigado por sua ajuda e compreensão. Irei marcar como correta sua reposta. Vlw mesmo :)

Comment: @GuilhermeLuis Ah é mesmo, assim tb funciona. Abs!